# My visual basic form is no longer accessible- how do I get to the code editor for it again?

Tags: vb.net

Noobie question: I created a multi-form and one of the forms (fQuizzes) still works but I cannot access the code anymore, it shows as "VB" in the Solution Explorer- how do I access the code and keep it as a form again?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you have in the Form's constructor? Do you have `InitializeComponent()` method.? First line.

Comment: For future reference, when taking a screenshot, only capture what you actually need. If all we need to see is the Solution Explorer then just capture the Solution Explorer. If you're using Windows 10 then you can use Snipping Tool or Snip & Sketch to capture just what's required.

Comment: If you click the *Show All Files* button on the Solution Explorer toolbar, is there a *fQuizzes.Designer.vb* item displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you've done to your code, your form no longer `Inherits Form` properly

Look what happens when I take a working Form:

[image]

And comment out the line that lets VB know it's a form:

[image]

Deleting or removing the FormName.Designer.vb from the project will also, implicitly, cause this to be true (the part where I said "no longer Inherits Form properly")

Comment: Well, this could be one of the many causes of the problem. He could have as well deleted the forms files manually.

Comment: I sort of addressed that with implication that *if the Inherits line in x.Designer.vb is "not there" then VB won't consider it a form*, but I've added an explicit mention for clarity, thanks